# Creating a large letter X

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a script that allows the user to enter a certain amount of rows which will then print a large letter X, so far I am able to print it as a v shape but am struggling to get the rest of the x together.

```js
rows = 0;
space = "&nbsp;";
var user_input = parseFloat(prompt("Enter how many rows:", 0));
while (rows < user_input) {
  space_counter = 0;
  while (space_counter < rows) { //process1
    document.write(space);
    space_counter++;
  }
  document.write("x"); //process2
  rows++;
  midspace_counter = 0;
  while (midspace_counter < user_input - rows) { //process3
    document.write(space + space);
    midspace_counter++;
  }
  document.write("x<br>"); //process4
  rows++;
}
```

Comment: `span { font-size: 300px; } <span>X</span>` big enough for ya?

Comment: Can you not simply reverse your process for the remaining rows?  (Of course you have to deal with the nun-duplicated middle row if the number of rows is odd, but that shouldn't be horrible.)

Answer (score 1):

How i would do that:

```
 let result = "";
 const maxRow = +prompt("how many rows?");
 // Knowing the half size of our x might be useful
 const half = (maxRow - 1) / 2;

 for(let row = 0; row < maxRow; row++){
   // For e.g. maxRow = 7 this will be 3 2 1 0 1 2 3
   const midspace = Math.abs(half - row);
   const pad = maxRow - midspace - 1;// 1 = "x"
   // \n means newline      
   result += " ".repeat(pad) + "x" + " ".repeat(midspace * 2) + "x\n";
}
```

Then you just need to append that to the document.